# Python subprocess.Popen communicate through a pipeline

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I want to be able to use `Popen.communicate` and have the stdout logged to a file (in addition to being returned from `communicate()`.

This does what I want - but is it really a good idea?

```
cat_task = subprocess.Popen(["cat"],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
tee_task = subprocess.Popen(["tee", "-a", "/tmp/logcmd"], stdin=cat_task.stdout, 
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
cat_task.stdout = tee_task.stdout #since cat's stdout is consumed by tee, read from tee.
cat_task.communicate("hello there")
('hello there', None)
```

Any issues with this, looking at communicate's impl it looks good. But is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "nicer", I would say that the following is probably nicer in the sense that it avoids having an additional tee process:

```
import subprocess

def logcommunicate(self, s):
    std = self.oldcommunicate(s)
    self.logfilehandle.write(std[0])
    return std

subprocess.Popen.oldcommunicate = subprocess.Popen.communicate
subprocess.Popen.communicate = logcommunicate
logfh = open("/tmp/communicate.log", "a")

proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.logfilehandle = logfh

result = proc.communicate("hello there\n")
print result
```

In a nutshell, it provides a wrapper for `communicate()` that writes stdout to a file handle of your choice, and then returns the original tuple for you to use. I've omitted exception handling; you should probably add that if the program is more critical. Also, if you expect to create several `Popen` objects and want them all to log to the same file, you should probably arrange for `logcommunicate()` to be thread-safe (synchronised per file handle). You can easily extend this solution to write to separate files for stdout and stderr.

Note that if you expect to pass a lot of data back and forth, then `communicate()` might not be the best option since it buffers everything in memory.