# Logging Process' STDIN and STDOUT

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to run a process with `subprocess.Popen()` and communicate with it through the python shell, like the `subprocess.Popen` usual behavior. Beside that, I would like to discursively log the STDIN and STDOUT to a logfile.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by discursively ? Do you mean they both log to the same file ?

Comment: yes, but not just append the STDOUT after the STDIN. I need it discursively so I can tell which input brought any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming discursively means rambling and rambling means all in the same file, then the following snippet is what you requested.

**Discursive logging with discrimination of the source and interaction**

Override its communicate method like similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456692/python-subprocess-popen-communicate-through-a-pipeline)

```
import subprocess

def logcommunicate(self, s):
    self.logfilehandle.write("Input "+s)
    std = self.oldcommunicate(s)

    self.logfilehandle.write("Output "+std[0])
    return std

subprocess.Popen.oldcommunicate = subprocess.Popen.communicate
subprocess.Popen.communicate = logcommunicate
logfh = open("/tmp/communicate.log", "a")

proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.logfilehandle = logfh

result = proc.communicate("hello there\n")
print result
```

**Discursive logging with discrimination of the source**

First use StringIO instead of files, then subclass StringIO to override its write method to open that appends timestamp and source. Then write a custom compare function that sorts based on timestamp and source, timestamp first and then source Input and then output

```
 with open("file.log","wb") as in logfile:
 out = MyOutPutStringIO.StringIO() 
 in = MyInputStringIO.StringIO()
 subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines = True, stdin=in, stdout=out)

 #Then after you are done
 linestotal = []
 for line in in.readlines():
     linestotal.append(line)
 for line in out.readlines():
     linestotal.append(line)

 linestotal.sort(customsortbasedontimestampandinput)

 for line in linestotal.readlines():
    logwrite.write(line)
```

**Discursive logging**

```
 with open("file.log","wb") as in logfile:
 subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines = True, stdin=logfile, stdout=logfile)
```

The opposite is shown below

**Cursive logging**

```
 with open("stdout.txt","wb") as out:
 with open("stderr.txt","wb") as err:
 with open("stdin.txt","wb") as in:
 subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines = True, stdin=in,stdout=out,stderr=err)
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough - I would like to communicate with the process through the python shell, like the subprocess.Popen usual behavior. Beside that, I would like to log the STDIN and STDOUT to a logfile.

Comment: The input comes from a file in your example... I want to control the process with the standard input interface. I also want the output to show on the python shell. The only difference is that I want to log all this input/output traffic.